# How do I find the version of WordPress I have from the source code?

Tags: debug, wordpress-version

Given a copy of WordPress installation, how do I find out what version it is from the source code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can find the version in `wp-includes/version.php`, the `$wp_version` variable.

It can also be found in the `readme.html` file in the root of the WordPress folder.

Comment: If you happen to be looking at a development version of WordPress, the number in readme.html may not be accurate.  For example, in the WordPress 3.6 development versions, readme.html continued to show "3.5" until Release Candidate 1.

Comment: Seems like the version is no longer included in readme.html. I am using wordpress 5.2.

Answer (score 3):

open your site and in  meta tag with name="generator"
for example

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.5.2" />
```

Comment: though a valid way of finding the version, this is not from the source code, rather its from the output of running the source code.